# Can I install a custom build of nginx using/overwriting AWS OpsWork's built-in unicorn::rails recipe?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Disclaimer: I'm a total AWS and especially OpsWorks noob. I am furiously reading both OpsWorks and Chef documentation in the hopes that my question is stupid/really easy.

On my app I'm using the [unicorn::rails](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/unicorn/recipes/rails.rb) built-in OpsWorks Chef recipe. I'm pretty sure unicorn::rails builds [nginx along the way](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/unicorn/recipes/rails.rb#L5) using this mysterious package call in [nginx/recipes/default.rb](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/nginx/recipes/default.rb#L21). The EC2 instance is using Ubuntu so the package manager is apt-get.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to do custom nginx build with a built-in OpsWorks Chef recipe?
2. If (a) is true, where does one modify the chef script to build nginx with modules?

I suspect I'll need to write a custom Chef script and add another layer to the stack. I was hoping to use the built-in recipes for as long as possible because I'm super new to AWS OpsWorks and Chef.

Comment: This might not be on-topic for Stack Overflow. I suspect [su], [webmasters.se] or [sf] might be a better fit.

Comment: thanks @theTinMan! I'll post it there. Do you know if there's a way for me to migrate a question there or should I just copy/paste?

Comment: It can be migrated if we vote to close it for being on the wrong Stack Exchange site. That could take days. Instead, you could copy/paste the info to the other site and then delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.

The opsworks nginx recipe installs the `nginx` [package](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_package.html):

```
package "nginx"
```

Chef uses the local package manager to complete this task. This is most likely rpm/yum on Amazon instances.

#### Alternatives

If you want to use a custom nginx build I would suggest using the main [nginx cookbook](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/nginx) and it's [source recipe](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/master/recipes/source.rb) to build and install nginx. There are [node attributes](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx#source) that configure the build.

You could also build your own [nginx rpm package](https://www.tekovic.com/adding-custom-modules-to-nginx-rpm) and make it available to your systems then have opworks install your rpm instead of `nginx` with minor modifications. This may be a slippery rpm slope to ride on though.

Comment: The aws docs here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/customizing.html  says you cannot override built in recipes with cookbooks of same name.
How do you suggest we add custom cookbook now?

Comment: It looks like you have to create a complete [custom layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/create-custom.html). Note that it also says you will end up with both the default nginx and your custom nginx installed. I would create a [wrapper cookbook](https://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) for the main nginx cookbook I linked to. In the wrapper implement all the [Opworks requirements](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/create-custom-setup.html) but calling out to nginx as much as possible.

Comment: I think the following is better - get apt cookbook, write custom cookbook to uninstall nginx if exists, apt-add-repository nginx, apt-get update, install nginx. 
manually running this worked, just have to get it working on chef; What say?